# Call controller from the view of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have a restaurant controller, and in the show method i render a form of another controller (dishes)

```
   #new.html.erb (from dishes controller)
   <%= render 'dishes/dish_form' %>

   #show.html.erb (from restaurant controller)
   <%= render template: 'dishes/new' %>
```

and this is the form:

```
<%= form_for @dish, :url => { :controller => "dishes", action_name => "create" } do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dish_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Add new dish' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but when i try so add a dish, i have this error
[image]
[image]

this is my dishes controller:

```
  def new
    @dish = Dish.new
  end

  def create
    @dish = Dish.new(dish_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dish.save
        format.html { redirect_to @restaurant, notice: 'dish was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: :restaurant }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'show', location: :restaurant }
        format.json { render json: @restaurant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end 

  private
    def dish_params
      params.require(:dish).permit(:avatar, :name, :description)
    end
```

and this are my models:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dish, inverse_of: :restaurant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dish
end

class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

im learning rails so maybe is a dumb error but im stuck

Comment: form_for @dish, not :dishes...

Comment: it stills no saving and i have to redirect to restaurant show, if i use @dish it wont find the show view of restaurants

Comment: i think is not saving because it dont receive the id_restaurant

Answer (score 0):

you should try to this to the controller action where the form is rendered

```
@dish = Dish.new
```

as you directly call the 'create' action rails is missing the instance variable Dish.new. Therefore the error message. Normally rails works like this:

```
def new
@dish = Dish.new
end
```

and than you call the create action on 'submit'. 
However, as it looks like you call the form from the #show action just add this code there and you will be fine. May be not the best solution but it will work like that. Add to #show

```
@dish = Dish.new
```

Sorry mate. Yes @dish is correct and not :dishes.

Comment: i already do that (question update), but i have the same error

Answer (score 0):

OK. 
My latest guess is that you want the restaurants to be able to create many dishes. 
So you should set up your models accordingly:

```
#restaurants_model
 has_many :dishes
#dishes_model
belongs_to :restaurant
```

next is that you add a column called restaurant_id to your dishes table 
`t.string :restaurant_id`

than in your restaurant controller #show

```
def show
end
```

if you use the routes as normal, e.g.

```
resources :restaurants
resources :dishes
```

the show action of the restaurant controller should give you a url that looks like this: localhost:3000/restaurants/1
where the 1 is the id of the restaurant.

This id you want to save to the dish by adding a hidden field

```
=f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, value: @restaurant.id
```

you need to permit the restaurant_id in the dishes controller params, e.g. dish_params. Just add

```
:restaurant_id
```

and it should be fine. This way the id will be saved to the dishes table and you can later call it from there. 
This gives you the chance to call @restaurant.dishes which will show all dishes of that restaurant.

If you just want to redirect back you can use `redirect :back`
Otherwise, you can try to integrate a helper to get the right restaurant using the hidden restaurant_id field

Comment: how can i get the restaurant id?

Comment: im rendering the view <%= render 'dishes/dish_form', :id => @restaurant.id %> but i cant access to the id in the dishes controller